# How to create embossed text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am wanting to create text that looks like the following image:

[image]

Comment: @all - This just looks like a go-to-my-blog question

Comment: I would have uploaded the picture I'm asking about but my reputation isn't high enough to.

Comment: Have fixed that for you :). Will retract my original comment and -1

Comment: This is one for the Graphic Design Stack Exchange - we only deal with Photoshop as it relates to photography here. However... <cough> Layer Styles </cough>

Comment: Haha, thank you for the <cough> hint </cough>

Comment: Does anyone know what font was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of sites on the internet that offer tutorials on this. Beveled Text, Embossed Text, Watermarking (same concept just alpha transparency raised)...

These are just random Google/Bing searches:

- http://www.sketchpad.net/photoshp.htm
- http://www.tutorial9.net/category/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/
- http://www.dwphotoshop.com/photoshop/bevel.php
- http://www.ehow.com/how_4421419_use-bevel-emboss-effects-photoshop.html
- http://www.developingwebs.net/photoshop/bevel.php

Even youtube:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpQ_jIqMwA

Or my best is [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Photoshop-training-tutorials/279-0.html). There is also [Kelby Training](http://kelbytraining.com/) & [KelbyTV](http://kelbytv.com/) but these are more from a photographic point of view than the software perspective.

But expect this to get migrated as advised in the comments

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know what the technique was called or I would have googled it myself. Thank you!!

Comment: Would you happen to know what font was used in the above image?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr - Sorry, I cannot tell you the font type used. I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdana may come close

Comment: The typeface is Myriad.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson - How do you verify that? Is it just experience? Or is that another question unto itself!

Comment: Mostly experience. It's a workhorse typeface that has the advantage of coming in several different weights so it's very versatile, and it's very clean for screen work (see the Apple website, for instance, which uses a variant of Myriad. The lowercase a, e and g are distinctive.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson - I Understand. You used unique markings to identify or rule out common typefaces and thus were able to understand the font being used.

Comment: Pretty much. Often-used fonts become as recognizable as human faces, especially when they have very distinctive characteristics. Trajan, Myriad, Futura, Helvetica, Times, Univers and other classics are in that category.

Answer (score 3):

if you want a simple way to do so and give it a little extra feel like this image:

[image]

You can find the 6-step tutorial here:
http://www.luukratief-design.nl/psd-files/creating-text-pressed-in-a-background/

Comment: and you can download this psd as well