# How do I make icons on an image background appear debossed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

[image]

I Am a beginner in Photoshop. I don't exactly know the name of the thing I have highlighted in the above image. How to make such contents on a background image? Do mention if it can be done using any other tools.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking... to me, the circled objects are buttons with icons with some dropshadows.

Comment: @VelS its created either with `inner shadows` or with `drop shadows` as well as slight bevel. Try applying both styles and play with the settings, its not too hard to figure out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create embossed text in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/how-to-create-embossed-text-in-photoshop)

Comment: There's also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18861/creating-sunken-text-in-coreldraw which describes the method (but is not Photoshop-specific).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click at an empty portion of your layer and choose "Blending Options". Then, play with "Bevel and Emboss" section.